# Wordpress print_r or echo from within hook callback

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to debug a function below. The print_r nor echo are not displaying anything though.  How can I print the contents of:
$order or $paypal_args ?

```
function custom_override_paypal_email1( $paypal_args, $order ) {
    print_r($paypal_args);
    print_r($order);
    // die();
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $product ) {
            $terms = get_the_terms($product['product_id'],'product_cat');
            if (!is_null($terms)){
                    if(count($terms)>0)
                    {
                        //get first one
                    $term = $terms[0];

                 if(strtolower($catName)==='ethics'){
                         $paypal_args['business'] = "zzz@zzz.example.com";
                     }
                     else{
                        // $t = strval($term);
                        $paypal_args['business'] = $t ."yyy@yyy.example.com";
                     }
                }
            }
        //  break;
        }
//      $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( "You must add a minimum of %s %s's to your cart to proceed." , 1, "T" ) );
    return $paypal_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args' , 'custom_override_paypal_email1', 10, 2  );
```

Whenever I run the function I am getting the following woocommerce notice:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Are you sure the function is actually being called? Does `die()` work?

Comment: Whenever I add die function hangs indefinitely. Still I can't see any output. I suspect that perhaps function is executed via ajax and that's why I don't see anything??
The code  $paypal_args['business'] = "xxx@xxx.com"; works when I take it out outside the for loop.

Comment: If die causes something to hang indefinitely, I assume you are performing an ajax request, and die is preventing any response from being given. In that case, you can put your `print_r()` back in, and you need to use the browser console to inspect what is happening when the ajax call is made.

Comment: Thank you. Can you submit it as an answer?

Comment: I use `error_log(json_encode($array))` and enable `WP_DEBUG_LOG` in `wp-config.php` when I need to see an array (or anything other variable) in a place that doesn't lend itself to `print_f()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are performing an Ajax request, the response will not be shown on the page. The `echo` or `print_r()` functions are working, but in order to see what is happening with Ajax responses you need to use the browser console.

You can access the console on most browsers by pressing F12. You will then be able to see the HTTP requests being made, and can examine what is happening with them.

Comment: That's exactly how I was able to troubleshoot the problem.